# How to use Browserify to run Node.js code through HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I installed Browserify and am loading it into my HTML file with:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I run the website from my `home.js` file, I am getting the following error, even though the `bundle.js` file exists and is right next to `home.js`:

> GET http://localhost:5000/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED

I am also getting this other error from my other JavaScript file (I think because Browserify wasn't imported as a result of the above error):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add a code example to give us a little insight into your issue.

Comment: You don't need to "import" browserify, it converts your code to a javascript file with the name you want. Normally bundle.js.
Browserify is a program you run with your code as input, not a library you load in the HTML.

Comment: edited error code formatting for readability, fixed capitalization errors, added 'browserify' tag

Comment: This doesn't seem like the issue is related to browserify. Your page, for whatever reason, is failing to retrieve the bundle.js file from the server.